# Frequency table (Modifying the code)

Tags: r

I use the below code to calculate the frequency table and keep only the levels with percentage value bigger than 0.1 . But I still want to show their percentages based on all observations in the data set. How can I modify the below code to show the percentage of specific levels based on all observation.

```
   library(ggplot2)
    library(rattle)
    library(plyr)
    levels <- names(which(summary(States$region)/sum(summary(States$region)) >0.1))
    table_ <- ggplot(States, aes(region ,fill=region))
    table_ <- table_ + geom_bar() 
    table_ <- table_ + theme(legend.position="none")
    table_ <- table_ + coord_flip()  
    table_ <- table_ + geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label = ifelse((..count..)==0,"",scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)))), stat="count",colour="black",vjust=1.0,size=4)+
                            scale_x_discrete(limit = levels)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question with an example ?

Comment: steveb, percentage=sum(MTN)/all observations in the data set and not just the selected levels

Comment: Putting aside that you would multiply by 100 to get the percentage, I did understand the part about how you calculate your result.  What is not clear is that you have a frequency table that is based on all observations, you are just plotting only those over `0.1`.  Can you clarify what your desired output should look like ?  I think once this is answered, it will be easy to point you in the correct direction.